# Кто нибудь пробовал бороться с такой ошибкой кодировки в mysql

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Есть 2 таблицы созданные когда то каким то скриптом, не суть.
На вид они полностью одинаковые с теми что создавались в ручную в dbforge
Но ключи между ними не устанавливаются. Борюсь обычным удалением и созданием заново таблицы. 
Хотя между собой у них ключи ставятся. Я так понимаю что то с кодировкой.

```
CREATE TABLE kulinar.roles_users (
  user_id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  role_id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
)
ENGINE = INNODB
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

...

```
CREATE TABLE kulinar.roles (
  id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  name varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  description varchar(255) NOT NULL
)
ENGINE = INNODB
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 5461
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

...

```
CREATE TABLE kulinar.users (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  username varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  photo varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  network varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  uid varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 9
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 5461
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После удаления и создания вручную все ок
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы пытаетесь связать *varchar* и *int*? и у таблицы имя, явно не укладывающееся в [требования](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin прочтите внимательней вам показалось

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте kulinar.users.id так же как и остальные связываемые поля UNSIGNED. И на сколько я понимаю вы приводите, новые запросы для создания таблиц, поэтому проверьте еще длину полей в связываемых полях.

Comment: Сразу тоже подумал что причина в длине полей, в одних таблицах была 10 в других 11, но потом удалил таблицы и создал из через sql скрипт попробовал связать, получилось тоже самое. Когда создал вручную через программу (создать новую таблицу и тд)  то как видно на скрине связь устанавливается